# Python Pandas: split and change the date format(one with eg:(aug 2018 - nov 2018)) and other with only one?

Tags: python, pandas

Split Date e.g. Aug 2018 --> 01-08-2018 ??

Here's my sample input

```
id      year_pass
1       Aug 2018 - Nov 2018
2       Jul 2017
```

Here's my sample input 2

```
id      year_pass
1                  Jul 2018
2       Aug 2017 - Nov 2018
```

What i did,
I'm able to split the date on the with eg:(aug 2018 - nov 2018)

```
# splitting the date column on the '-'
year_start, year_end = df['year_pass'].str.split('-')
df.drop('year_pass', axis=1, inplace=True)

# assigning the split values to columns
df['year_start'] = year_start
df['year_end'] = year_end

# converting to datetime objects
df['year_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_start'])
df['year_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_end'])
```

But couldn't figure out how to do it for both

Output should be:

```
id      year_start    year_end
1       01-08-2018    01-11-2018
2       01-07-2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by splitting the strings by the original dataframe:

```
# split the original dataframe
df = df.year_pass.str.split(' - ', expand=True)

      0        1
id                  
1   Aug2018  Nov2018
2   Jul2017     None
```

And then apply `pd.to_datetime` to turn the strings to datetime objects and format them using `strftime`:

```
# rename the columns
df.columns = ['year_start','year_end']
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), axis=0)

    year_start    year_end
id                        
1   01-08-2018  01-11-2018
2   01-07-2017         NaT
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Can you help me out on sample input 2 in edited answer

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year_pass": ["Aug 2018 - Nov 2018", "Jul 2017"]})
df[["year_start", 'year_end']] = df["year_pass"].str.split(" - ", expand=True)
df["year_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_start']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df["year_end"] =  pd.to_datetime(df['year_end']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df.drop('year_pass', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   year_start    year_end
0  01-08-2018  01-11-2018
1  01-07-2017         NaT
```

---

**Edit as per comment:**

```
import pandas as pd

def replaceInitialSpace(val):
    if val.startswith(" "):
        return " - "+val.strip()
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame({"year_pass": ["           Jul 2018", "Aug 2018 - Nov 2018", "Jul 2017           "]})
df["year_pass"] = df["year_pass"].apply(replaceInitialSpace) 
df[["year_start", 'year_end']] = df["year_pass"].str.split(" - ", expand=True)
df["year_start"] = pd.to_datetime(df['year_start']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df["year_end"] =  pd.to_datetime(df['year_end']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
df.drop('year_pass', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   year_start    year_end
0         NaT  01-07-2018
1  01-08-2018  01-11-2018
2  01-07-2017         NaT
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Can you help me out on sample input 2 in edited answer

Comment: Updated answer..Note this works only if the value starts with a space...

Answer (score 1):

If need datetimes in output is necessary different format - `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
df1 = df.pop('year_pass').str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True).apply(pd.to_datetime)
df[['year_start','year_end']] = df1
print (df)
   id year_start   year_end
0   1 2018-08-01 2018-11-01
1   2 2017-07-01        NaT

print (df.dtypes)
id                     int64
year_start    datetime64[ns]
year_end      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

If need change format then get strings, but all datetimelike functions failed:

```
df1 = (df.pop('year_pass').str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True)
        .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
        .replace('NaT',''))
df[['year_start','year_end']] = df1
print (df)

   id  year_start    year_end
0   1  01-08-2018  01-11-2018
1   2  01-07-2017      

print (df.dtypes)
id             int64
year_start    object
year_end      object
dtype: object

print (type(df.loc[0, 'year_start']))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Can you help me out on sample input 2 in edited answer

Comment: @showrya - So you need working with datetime column later? Because question is if need datetimes or strings in output data.

Comment: @showrya - but if need strings and instead `NaT` empty string then check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks just need strings